# The plus button next to "Build" in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit an app for iOS but the plus button next to Build does not appear.I uploaded two screenshots for iPhone and iPad but i did not upload any app preview in iTunesConnect.

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you click the little red circle with the ! in it? And of course you won't see the + until you actually submit a build and you then get an email from Apple telling you that the binary has finished being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload your signed binary to itunesconnect in order for it to appea there.

You either upload it using Xcode (product>archive) once archived the organizer window appears, on the right you have a blue button, upload to appstore.

or you can export it sign it with your developer identity and upload it through application loader